# Get FileZilla Server version from command line

Tags: command-line, filezilla, command-line-arguments

Is there any way how to get FileZilla server version from command line? Client can do this. `FileZillaServer.exe /v`, `FileZillaServer.exe /version` or the same with dash does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Server)) does not list a command line argument for this. As such, I don't believe this is possible through a switch.

However, you can in a sense use Powershell to achieve this, with the command:

`(Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Filezilla Server\Filezilla Server.exe").VersionInfo`